# FileNotFoundException - missing checkpoint.parquet in delta_log

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, pyspark

I have got a few jobs which are performing each day. Unfortunately, some of them sometimes randomly throw an exception:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: _delta_log/00000000000000000070.checkpoint.parquet`

The problem is that this error is not constant, sometimes the job throws it, sometimes not so looking for a cause is like looking for a needle in a haystack.

I had a similar issue a few months ago, I have found somewhere that updating Databricks Runtime Version to 5.5 will solve the problem. Sure, it solved, but after a few months the error comes back and I can't find any reasonable solution on how to prevent it.

Does somebody have to force this problem and found a solution how to prevent it?

I'll be really thankful for any kind of suggestion and help!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a known transient issue with Databricks and Databricks team is aware of this.

Here is the workaround suggested by Databricks team:

Disable log cleanup. E.g.,

```
    %sql
ALTER TABLE 
SET TBLPROPERTIES (
  'delta.enableExpiredLogCleanup' = 'false',
)
```

Make sure generate more than 2 checkpoints (in other words, more than 30 commits) in 2 days.

Increase the Delta table property "checkpointRetentionDuration" and make sure during this new duration, there are more than 2 checkpoints (in other words, more than 30 commits) created. E.g.,

```
%sql
ALTER TABLE 
SET TBLPROPERTIES (
  'delta.checkpointRetentionDuration' = '7 days',
)
```

The fix which was provided by Databricks Team  is to make sure you won't get the issue again. Databricks team is working on permanent fix for this soon.

Comment: Has this been fixed since this post? And either way, is there a link to an issue tracker for it?